# How to programmatically launch Skype in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Putting directly: Assuming that I've **Skype** already installed in my OS, how can I launch a dialer **from my app**, with a given phone number passed as a parameter, from a Windows Phone?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of last October 2014, the 2.24 release support Skype Uri's, and you can now launch Skype on Windows Phone 8.1 with `skype://12345678?call` as uri (with `1234678` being the phone number)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745878(v=office.15).aspx for some documentation on the syntax.

*(Disclaimer: I work on the Skype for Windows Phone team)*

Comment: if i wanna send link like skype:user?call to windows phone from nfc tag, skype will not launch

Comment: We haven't implemented support for NFC yet.

Comment: Skype has not yet registered its uri format with windows phone yet. Let hope they come with that soon!

Comment: Mhm, perhaps we should, yes. I'll check if it's scheduled for a release when I come back from Africa.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen - Has the situation changed (launching Skype from a Windows Phone 7 app)?  If not, is you do it by launching a web page with a Skype click to call link to the desired number in the web component?

Comment: Click2Call on websites is a feature currently not available. I can't comment on future availability.

Comment: I'm also looking for this feature. The phone app, mail app, and text meesage app all support this for Windows Phone 8.1. Skype is also a first party app. Yet it does not conform to the other first party apps' behavior. Why is this? Reference the following video as an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc

Comment: Skype is not a first party app.

Comment: You can now use Skype Uri's to launch Skype as of 2.24 which was released the other week.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Any ideas on which Launcher to use? `WebBrowserTask` works (via URL but not Uri) but leaves ugly empty Explorer window after the call. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can. With Windows Phone you can use launchers which launch a predefined set of OS installed apps such as e-mail, maps, etc.

The closest you can get is using the phone call task.

Check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769550(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope that helps. Inter-app communication isn't really there yet.

// Jed

Comment: The PhoneCallTask won't launch Skype :)

Comment: I know. I was just letting him know his closest alternative.

Answer (score 1):

[Skype API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745880(v=office.15).aspx) for WinJS provides some documentation.

Sadly, the examples are in JavaScript.

Here's the initial syntax:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("skype:"));
```

Calling somebody would look something like this:
Example: One-to-one dialog

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("skype:skype.test.user.1?call"));
```

However, I'm not aware on how to retrieve Skype contacts within another application.
This can be done with contacts on the people hub app.

See an app example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc).