# How to share my skype contact on a windows phone's app

Tags: windows-phone-8, skype

Is it possibile share my skype contact in a windows phone app?

I don't have any ideas about do it!

Comment: What do you mean by "share my skype contact"? Do you want to initiate a Skype call?

Comment: For example in Html I use : <a href="skype:mycontact" ></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, initiating Skype calls is not currently possible (check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425171/50468) from a WP Skype developer).